# 'Transaction is not active' após receber erro por não conseguir deletar

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Galera to tentado montar um crud para estudo e me deparei com a seguinte situação.

Estou usando JPA e Hibernate.

Ao tentar deletar um registro a qual tenha referencia em outra tabela é lançado um Exception dizendo que não pode deletar pq tem referência, até ai ok.

Depois que aparece essa Exceção se eu tentar adicionar outro item aparece a mesma exceção que mostrou quando tentei deletar e logo abaixo 'Transaction is not active' o que pode estar acontecendo?

DAO

```
public T inserir(T entity) throws Exception {
    try {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return entity;
}`

public void excluir(T entity) {
    try {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.remove(entity);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

RN

```
public Item inserir(Item item){
    try {
        return geralDAO.inserir(item);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }       
}

public void excluir(Item item){
    try {
        geralDAO.excluir(item);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Erro ao deletar", e.getMessage());          
    }       
}
```

Comment: Apresente a implementação, fica mais fácil de adivinhar.

Comment: a maneira que estou utilizando coloquei agora na pergunta acima @Matheus

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você ta criando o `factory` e o `manager` no `construtor`, porém a cada operação, tem de ser fechado a `conexão`. A implementação "correta", seria criar o factory e o manager em cada método, e fecha-lás depois da operação.

Ex:

```
public void setProdutos(ProdutosVO produto) throws Exception{
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("model");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

        manager.getTransaction().begin();    
        manager.persist(produto);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();  

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        throw new Exception(e);
    }finally {
        manager.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, cara vou fazer um teste aqui pra ver o que ocorre

Comment: Então @Mattheus se eu criar factory e o manager em cada método vai ficar foda, pode gerar uma lentidão grotesca no servidor. Eu pensei que poderia ser por eu não estar fechando as transações que estava causando o erro. Mas continuo na mesma

Comment: Erros recebidos: A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!.

Comment: faz o .close()  tb quando cair no catch , ou usa finally.

Comment: tentei já mano e nada.

Comment: mano, como não consegui resolver de outro jeito fiz o seguinte: Antes de deletar verifico se o item tem fk na outra table.. valeu. Vou me aprofundar em jpa/hibernate.. valeu mano @Matheus